# Loading plugin reference in app.js : NativeScript

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, nativescript

I'm developing a NativeScript app which involves push notifications.Whenever push notification came I need to store notification contents into database.

For that I have written some code in "onMessageReceived" function.This code is in the page in which GCM registration code is there.

If app is running then every thing working fine. The problem is if app is closed then "onMessageReceived" function is not even executing(I checked with console logs).

So for that I'm trying to place "onMessageReceived" function in app.js so that even app is closed it will execute.For that I'm trying to import the "nativescript-push-notifications" in app.js, but getting error saying **"application is null,it's not passed correctly"**.Below is my app.js code.

**app.js**

```
var application = require("application");
var gcm=require("nativescript-push-notifications");
if(gcm.onMessageReceived) {
    gcm.onMessageReceived(function callback(data) { 
    console.log("message received:::: ", "" + JSON.stringify(data));
    storeInDatabase(data);// some function to store notification content into db. 

});
 }
application.mainModule="main-page";
application.start({ moduleName: "main-page" });
```

Can we import **"nativescript-push-notifications"** reference in app.js??

Any suggestions will be helpful.Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Application is null because your app has not started yet try adding the plugin in the application launch event

```
var application = require("application");
application.start({ moduleName: "main-page" });
application.on(application.launchEvent, function (args) {
    if (args.android) {
        var gcm = require("nativescript-push-notifications");
        gcm.register({ senderID: 'conversate-1148' }, function (data) {
            self.set("message", "" + JSON.stringify(data));
        }, function () { });
        if (gcm.onMessageReceived) {
            gcm.onMessageReceived(function callback(data) {
                console.log("message received:::: ", "" + JSON.stringify(data));
                 storeInDatabase(data);// some function to store notification content into db. 

            });
        }

    } else if (args.ios !== undefined) {
        //Do ios stuff here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.Adding the plugin in application launch event is working.But still if app is closed then **"gcm.onMessageReceived" ** function is not executing.Please help I got stuck only in this particular scenario.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Osei's code you might want to check out your AndroidManifest.xml file (generated in your platforms/android folder) and make sure the following permissions are set :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

and also that the plugin is registered as a service in the same AndroidManifest.xml file as follows:

```
<activity android:name="com.telerik.pushplugin.PushHandlerActivity"/>
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.pushApp.gcm" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.telerik.pushplugin.PushPlugin" android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.I have already checked AndroidManifest.xml every thing is as expected.What my problem is, if app is closed then notification is coming but **" onMessageReceived "** function is not executing.

Comment: Might be problem of payload.